# Is there a link between Isolation and wisdom?

Tags: wisdom

In history many people that lived a life of isolation turned out to write the laws of the universe,great inventors that advanced society forever with ideas and inventions. Others started a spiritual movement for mankind that millions follow I will name just a few are linked to isolation.

First look at Albert Einsteins quote on Buddhism- http://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-the-religion-of-the-future-will-be-a-cosmic-religion-the-religion-which-based-on-experience-albert-einstein-61-69-74.jpg

Buddha-http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1428
Jesus Christ-https://thonyc.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/isaac-newton-the-last-lone-genius/
Albert Einstein-http://scientific-child-prodigy.blogspot.com/2007/05/albert-einstein-on-gifted-isolation.html
Nikola Tesla-http://www.history.com/news/history-lists/9-things-you-may-not-know-about-nikola-tesla
More-http://zenhabits.net/creative-habit/

Comment: When you ask about "isolation" what do you exactly mean? Maybe you could give a definition of it. Isolation is a broad word with many aspects. Are you thinking of isolation as in a solitary retreat? There are monks who do solitary retreats for months, even years in a row.

Comment: Yes solitary retreat by choice. For years at a time with very little contact with society.Not by a disorder or lack of social skills or old age.But in the prime of ones life, to sacrifice this special time to humble the mind and learn to know who we are.Alone in the world.

Comment: @Mr. Cruz. It would be a good idea to add that information to your question.

Comment: Maybe if you just mention if there is a link between isolation and wisdom then it will be sufficient sans the back ground in the body of the question which might be confusing every one. In Theravada Buddhism there are at least 2 links that I know of.

Comment: @ Suminda Sirinath Salpitikorala - I've experienced the phenomena and noticed intuition and other changes after a just a few  months, 3 years later I started to search for a relation to what i found and some very important people also choose isolation for some strange reason.

Comment: Some of the people you mention are not Buddhists. It will be good if you can put this purely in a Buddhist perspective how this can help spiritual perspective. This will also narrow down the scope to the Buddhist perspective.

Comment: @Suminda Sirinath Salpitikorala- We can all become like Buddha and that is what he wants Suminda Sirinath Salpitikorala.Showing proof that Buddha was a real man and his life was as true as the other men I mentioned will only bring more to Buddhism. These men didnt want to be followed or worshiped and neither did Buddha.Im not comparing them to Buddha but proving that Buddhas life style made him very special and unique and forever known

Comment: Even if the question were, "Is there a link between isolation and the Buddha's enlightenment?" or "Does the Buddha recommend isolation as a practice?" that would still be quite a broad (perhaps too broad) question, which I think has a "yes and no" answer, isn't that so? And, are you hoping to read people's answering using references (e.g. answers from scripture), or, answers based on their personal experience[s]?

Comment: The links to these people and isolation are all proven. Should I post a link to all there lives as a mean of proof? because I can do that if thats whats needed.

Comment: @Mr.Cruz. As I have mentioned earlier, you should add the information to your question, in order to make it easier understandable and to increase clarity.

Comment: @ChrisW This will not be too broad as there is at least one Sutta which deals with just this but down it leads to Spiritual development and final enlightenment.

Comment: This is called `Viveka nissita` in Pali of "Dependent on Solitude" forumula "Liberation Depedent on Solitude" in English. This one quote on it "Formula of attaining the goal: The viveka,nissita (The Dependent-on-Solitude Formula) pericope is one of the most important formulas commonly found in the sutta ... dependent on solitude ... ". Maybe edit the question if needed but this topics so far has not been brought up on this site and in Theravada perspective (among who gives importance to the Suttas) is pretty important.

Comment: is OP seeking to get information with this question, and if yes, what kind of information is he expecting to get? Or is this more like a statement that declares OP's insight/position and he is looking for confirmation of that?